# Why neo4j balloons storage?

Tags: neo4j

When creating the rating relations for the [large MovieLens dataset](http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/latest/), the ~600mb cvs file with the 22m ratings balloons into ~10gb in Neo4j.

```sql
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///ratings.csv' AS line
MERGE (movie: Movie {id: TOINT(line.`movieId`)})
MERGE (user: User {id: TOINT(line.`userId`)})
with movie, user, line
MERGE (user)-[r:RATED]->(movie)
SET r.rating = TOINT(line.`rating`);
```

The following constraints are also in place:

```sql
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON  (m:Movie) ASSERT m.id IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON  (u:User) ASSERT u.id IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON  (g:Genre) ASSERT g.genres IS UNIQUE;
```

and movies and users nodes are already created.

Is there a way to more efficiently (storage-wise) create these  relations?

Comment: This is probably a great question to ask Neo Technology directly. It's not a programming question though - more of an implementation detail of Neo4j.

Comment: Try hardware calculator [ http://neo4j.com/hardware-sizing-calculator/ ] to calculate estimated size on disk.

Comment: Another calculator: https://sgerogia.github.io/Disk-Capacity-Planning-for-Neo4J/

Comment: Thanks @stdob--. According to the calculator the "Estimated size on disk [is] 742 MB". Therefore, the naïve way the relations are defined above is probably causing this effect. However, both MERGE and MATCH on the movies and users cause this and I'm out of ideas

Comment: according to http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/20m/ there are ~165,000 nodes. Either way, it's still a long way to ~10gb

Comment: What size of `neostore.transaction.db*` files?

Comment: There are dozens of neostore.transaction.db.* produced upon creating the relations, each 251mb! The final size after deleting them is 1.66GiB which is still not cheap but at least more sensible. I suppose this answers the question

Comment: @blouzak And do not forget, by the way, periodically clean `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a large amount of disk space is a [`logical logs`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-logical-logs.html).

So, you can simple stop `neo4j`, delete `neostore.transaction.db.*`, then restart `neo4j`.

Or (best way) set `keep_logical_logs` property in value like this:

```
keep_logical_logs = 1G size
```